# Load static page in Django for Dev purposes

Tags: python, django, static, django-urls

I am a Front-End dev with 0 Django experience.  I am working on an existing Django app and need to add a few static pages before handing off to a Python developer. I only need to add these static pages for his reference, they will not exist as static pages on the live site.  What is the best way to do this? Here is my url.py file:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings
from views import issues
from django.shortcuts import redirect

urlpatterns = []


if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += patterns('',
        url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {
            'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT,
        }),
)

urlpatterns += patterns('refeed.views.account',
    url(r'^account/$', 'index'),
    url(r'^account/login/', 'login', name='login'),
    url(r'^account/logout/', 'logout'),
    url(r'^account/create/', 'create'),
    url(r'^account/delete_user/(\d+)', 'delete_user'),
    url(r'^account/create_user/', 'create_user'),
    url(r'^account/edit_user/(\d+)', 'edit_user'),
    url(r'^account/unsubscribe/(?P<account_id>\d+)/(?P<key>[A-Fa-f0-9]+)$',
        'unsub_recipient', name='unsubscribe_from_account_lists'),
    url(r'^account/unsubscribe/(?P<account_id>\d+)/(?P<issue_id>\d+)/(?P<key>[A-Fa-f0-9]+)$',
        'unsub_recipient', name='unsubscribe_from_account_by_issue'),
    url(r'^account/(\d+)/newsletter_archive.xml$', 'view_archive_xml'),
    url(r'^account/(\d+)/rss.xml$', 'view_rss'),
)

urlpatterns += patterns('refeed.views.issues',
    url(r'^issues/$', 'index'),
    url(r'^issues/(\d+)$', 'view', name='view_issue'),
    url(r'^issues/create$', issues.create, name='create_issue'),
    url(r'^issues/create_ajax$', 'create_ajax', name='create_issue_ajax'),
    url(r'^issues/(\d+)/edit$', issues.edit, name='edit_issue'),
    url(r'^issues/(\d+)/delete$', 'delete'),
    url(r'^issues/(\d+)/edit_and_resend$', 'edit_and_resend'),
    url(r'^issues/(\d+)/sort_stories$','sort_stories'),
    url(r'^issues/(\d+)/newsletter$','newsletter', name='preview_newsletter'),
    url(r'^issues/(\d+)/create_campaign$','create_campaign'),
    url(r'^issues/(\d+)/send_test$','send_test'),
    url(r'^issues/(\d+)/send$','send'),
    url(r'^issues/(\d+)/send_confirmation$', 'send_confirmation', name='send_confirmation'),
    url(r'^issues/(\d+)/delete_story/(\d+)$','delete_story'),
    url(r'^issues/(\d+)/view_archived$','view_archived'),
    url(r'^issues/unsubscribe_requests_csv$', 'unsubscribe_requests_csv',
            name='unsubscribe_requests_csv'),
    url(r'^issues/(\d+)/stat_csv/(unsubscribed|stories|clicked|bounced|opened)/$', 'stat_csv', name='issue_stat_csv'),

)

urlpatterns += patterns('refeed.views.feeds',
    url(r'^feeds/$', 'list'),
    url(r'^feeds/create$', 'create', name='create_feed'),
    url(r'^feeds/(\d+)/edit$', 'edit'),
    url(r'^feeds/(\d+)/edit_ajax$', 'edit_ajax', name='edit_feed_ajax'),
    url(r'^feeds/create_ajax$', 'create_ajax', name='create_feed_ajax'),
    url(r'^feeds/(\d+)/delete$', 'delete'),
    url(r'^feeds/(\d+)/delete_ajax$', 'delete_ajax', name='delete_feed_ajax'),
)

urlpatterns += patterns('refeed.views.stories',
    url(r'^$', lambda x:redirect('/stories/import')),
    url(r'^stories/$', 'index'),
    url(r'^stories/spider_for_story_img$', 'spider_for_story_img', name='spider_for_story_img'),
    url(r'^stories/create$', 'create'),
    url(r'^stories/(\d+)/edit$', 'edit'),
    url(r'^stories/(\d+)/delete_image_ajax$', 'delete_image_ajax'),
    url(r'^stories/(\d+)/delete$', 'delete'),
    url(r'^stories/(\d+)/delete_ajax$', 'delete_ajax', name='delete_story_ajax'),
    url(r'^stories/(\d+)/unbookmark_ajax$', 'unbookmark_ajax', name='unbookmark_ajax'),
    url(r'^stories/move_to_issue$', 'move_to_issue'),
    url(r'^stories/import$', 'import_stories'),
    url(r'^stories/import_ajax$', 'import_stories_ajax', name='load_all_feeds'),
    url(r'^stories/update_order_ajax$', 'update_order_ajax', name='stories_update_order_ajax'),
    url(r'^stories/get_current_stories/(\d+)', 'get_current_stories', name='get_current_stories'),
    url(r'^stories/get_images_json$','get_images_json'),
    url(r'^stories/upload_image$','upload_image'),
    url(r'^stories/bookmarks$','index_bookmarks'),

)

urlpatterns += patterns('refeed.views.categories',
    url(r'^categories/$', 'list'),
    url(r'^categories/create$', 'create'),
    url(r'^categories/create_ajax$', 'create_ajax', name='create_category_ajax'),
    url(r'^categories/(\d+)/edit$', 'edit'),
    url(r'^categories/(\d+)/delete$', 'delete'),
    url(r'^categories/sort_categories','sort_categories'),
)

urlpatterns += patterns('refeed.views.magazine',
    url(r'^view/(\d*)$', 'view_toc'),
    url(r'^view/(\d*)/category/(\d*)$', 'view_cat'),
    url(r'^view/(\d*)/story/(\d*)$', 'view_story'),
    url(r'^view/(\d*)/resources$', 'resources'),
    url(r'^view/(\d*)/toc_json$', 'toc_json'),
    url(r'^view/style$', 'css_style'),
)

urlpatterns += patterns('refeed.views.setting',
    url(r'^settings/$', lambda x:redirect('/account')),
    url(r'^settings/magazine$', 'magazine'),
    url(r'^settings/newsletter$', 'newsletter', name='newsletter_settings'),
    url(r'^settings/packages$', 'list_packages'),
)

urlpatterns += patterns('refeed.views.recipient_lists',
    url(r'^recipient-lists/$', 'index', name='recipient_lists_index'),
    url(r'^recipient-lists/create$', 'create'),
    url(r'^recipient-lists/drag_csv_create$', 'drag_csv_create', name='drag_csv_create'),
    url(r'^recipient-lists/(\d+)/drag_csv_edit$', 'drag_csv_edit', name='drag_csv_edit'),
    url(r'^recipient-lists/(\d+)/edit$', 'edit'),
    url(r'^recipient-lists/(\d+)/delete', 'delete'),
    url(r'^recipient-lists/(?P<recipient_list_id>\d+)/csv/(?P<csv_type>valid|invalid|unsubs|dupes)/$', 'download_csv', name='recipient_list_csv'),
)

urlpatterns += patterns('refeed.views.images',
    url(r'^stories/(\d+)/images/(\d+)/recrop$', 'recrop'),
    url(r'^images/updateall$', 'updateall'),
)

urlpatterns += patterns('refeed.views.webhooks',
    url(r'^webhooks/mandrill$', 'mandrill_webhook', name='mandrill_webhook'),
)
```

Comment: by static pages, do you mean render only template without writing a view?

Comment: if all you need are static pages, why use django? Just send him the html files and he can use that as a reference. Make sure that the css/js is in the right relative path tho, or opening it as a file:// won't work.

Comment: @v1k45 yes precisely

Answer (score 0):

You can use a TemplateView to directly render a template without writing a view.
You must import it and then tell it to render something:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^about/', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="about.html")),
]
```

This is in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/class-based-views/#simple-usage-in-your-urlconf).

Comment: I have tried the above many times and I have read that this is the correct approach in the docs, but for some reason I can't get it to work.  Is there a specific place in my above urls.py that I need to put this.  I still get the error "Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/info/"

Comment: url(r'^info/$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="about.html"))
Be careful with the path of the template.

Answer (score 0):

For rendering django templates without having to write views, you can use [`TemplateView`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/class-based-views/base/#django.views.generic.base.TemplateView)

In your urls.py:

```
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

# ... [other url confs] ...

urlpatterns += patterns('',
    url(r'^info/$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="info.html")),
)
```

Since your all urlpatterns are in a single file and use django's `patterns`, we used the same approach in the above url pattern too. Otherwise, you should declare URLConfs like the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/class-based-views/#simple-usage-in-your-urlconf) suggests.